# Powerpoint: How to repeat a picture without placing it in the masterslides?

Tags: powerpoint

I want to make a template for my colleagues. They should be able to place the customer logo on the first slide and then have the logo on all slides. I don't want them to open the masterslides and place the logo there, because this will cause human errors.

My idea would be to put a placeholder for pictures on all slides and link the contents, so that when a picture is placed in one of them, that the others show the same picture. But I can't find an option for that.

Anyone got an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint doesn't do this "out of the box". You'd need to provide a programmed solution (eg. in the form of an add-in) that would do the job for them, either by letting them insert an image then copying it to each slide OR by copying it to the slide master or one or more layouts.

This will take whatever shapes you have selected and dupe them on each slide in the presentation (so they sit atop anything else on each slide). As they're pasted onto each slide, they're "tagged" so they can be identified later. If you run the macro again, it first deletes any shapes it's tagged, so you don't wind up with lots of duplicates.

```
Sub DupeAcrossAllSlides()
Dim oShRange As ShapeRange
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oDupeShrange As ShapeRange
Dim x As Long

' Delete any old duped shapes
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For x = oSl.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Len(oSl.Shapes(x).Tags("Dupe")) > 0 Then
            oSl.Shapes(x).Delete
        End If
    Next
Next

Set oShRange = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
oShRange.Copy

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    Set oDupeShrange = oSl.Shapes.Paste
    For Each oSh In oDupeShrange
        oSh.Tags.Add "Dupe", oSh.Name
    Next
Next
oShRange.Delete

End Sub
```